# Java List PhoneBook

Tags: java, list

I have the following structure:

```
Person{
    int phoneNumber;
    String firstName;
    String secondName;
}
```

- I have to implement this structure in Java using list, array (does’n matter).
- I have a string, something like “Jon”. A method should display all firstNames that contains “Jon”.
  Example: Jonathan, Jones.
- One method that should order my list by firstName, secondName, phoneNumber.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of Persons like this:

```
List<Person> phoneBook = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

You can then filter out the List like this:
Java7:

```
List<Person> foundPersons = new ArrayList<>();
for (Person person : phoneBook) {
    if (person.firstName.contains("Jon")) {
        foundPersons.add(person);
    }
}
```

or Java8:

```
List<Person> foundPersons = phoneBook.stream().filter((person) -> {
    return person.firstName.contains("jon");
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Sorting can be easily done with the `List.sort()` method if the Person class **implements** the `Comparable` interface or by sending a `Comparator<Person>` instance to the same method.

Comment: Iti multumesc! Am vazut ca esti roman. :)

Comment: @GabrielComănescu What?

Comment: we share the same nationality, he thanked me for that. :)

Comment: @glglgl sorry for that, i only said thanks!